# Is there a way to change values of elements if they use a specific browser?

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, browser

For example, if in php i printed this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

and used a variable, lets say `$bname` then used an `if()` statement, could i change the value of an element such as a link `<a>` etc. to whatever i wanted? alternatively is there a way in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Watch that you do not get the languages muddled, that sounded a little confused.

Comment: yes i know.. i go about things very dirty and get myself into all sorts of trouble.

Comment: you could do this with js or jquery but as php is server side you would need to send what browser back to the script... or use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in php to determine the browser, tho its unreliable as can be altered

Comment: It's not recommended to base your logic in a specific browser vendor and/or version. You can better work with browser capabilities instead.

Comment: @Sander Pham - i have a specific problem that i will happily go dirty on to achieve the results i need

Comment: @Ricki: Sander's point is that a lot of the cross-browser problems faced are better checked directly, rather than relying on a browser check. [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) exists for this reason and is the *preferred* way of checking things.  But it does not cover all issues, so [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) remains.  From the website: **"We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this on jQuery. Using [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) as easy as this example.

```
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
     //do stuff for webkit browsers
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) may be used PHP side.

Alternatively, with jQuery, you can use the [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) flags.

Comment: `$.browser` is deprecated. These will be removed in some future version

Comment: @Raynos: If you look at my comments on the main question, you will see that I stated that.